# How to create the django rest auth social login?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have been trying to create a social login in django-rest-framework using django-rest-auth, but could not able to do it properly. I am a noob in these technologies and wants to create API for social login. Need Help in this.

I have tried all the tutorials that are at the top in google search but they are incomplete or hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with django-rest-framework-social-oauth2, you can see a good example with facebook in its README page.

https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2